# ERROR AL SUBIR UN ARCHIVO MOVE_UPLOADED_FILE

Tags: php

He tratado de subir un archivo con el metodo move_upload_file, el problema es que cuando lo sube al servidor desde la pagina, aparece el archivo vacio en la carpeta del servidor, vale decirsolo con el nombre y la extension.

Comment: Añade el código que tienes para que podamos ayudarte mejor. Saludos

Comment: Hola monsalve90 te saludo y te invito a revisar [ask] que te da brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Debes más especifico, puedes dividir tu pregunta que es amplia en varias preguntas.  Realiza el [tour] para obtener tu primer medalla.